# How to add SEO plugin in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, seo

i am using codeigniter. I want to add seo plugin.I found some code,but i don't know how to apply it.My code is,

```
controllers/seo.php
Class Seo extends CI_Controller {

    function sitemap()
    {

        $data = "";//select urls from DB to Array
        header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
        $this->load->view("sitemap",$data);
    }
}

views/sitemap.php
<?= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>

<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url();?></loc> 
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>

    <!-- My code is looking quite different, but the principle is similar -->
    <?php foreach($data as $url) { ?>
    <url>
        <loc><?= base_url().$url ?></loc>
        <priority>0.5</priority>
    </url>
    <?php } ?>

</urlset>


config/routes.php
$route['seo/sitemap\.xml'] = "seo/sitemap";
```

How it works on search engine?Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The code pasted by you contains code for 3 files as it shows.
i) controller class of codeigniter application/controllers/seo.php
ii) A view that is loaded by sitemap function of the seo controller. application/views/sitemap.php that outputs an XML Sitemap file.
iii) and a route to be added to the application/config/routes.php

**NOTE: The main and only function in this code is incomplete so is useless as it is. You need to add few lines to retrieve data from database & assign it to $data variable.**

Once completed it can be used as path to sitemap of your website that will managed via database.

I hope I was able to it make it clear.